# How to YARD-document return type of method with yield?

Tags: ruby, code-documentation, yard

I would like to better document the return type of this naïve memoization method using YARD:

```
# Ensures that given block is only executed exactly once and on subsequent
# calls returns result from first execution. Useful for memoizing methods.
#
# @param key [Symbol]
#   Name or unique identifier of the method that is being memoized
# @yield
# @return [Object] Whatever the block returns
def memoize(key, &_block)
  return @memos[key] if @memos.key?(key)

  @memos[key] = yield
end
```

*Note: there's an empty hash `@memos` being initialized on this class' `#initialize` method.*

Now, it would be great to express that **this method always returns whatever the given block returns**, but am not sure how to best do this. I thought of using `@yieldreturn` but would then need something like a *generic* to express something similar to:

```
# @yieldreturn [<T>]
# @return [<T>] Whatever the block returns
```

but that's not valid YARD, I believe.

Is there any way of expressing this connection of the return type and the provided block? Any suggestion is appreciated :)

Comment: I'd probably just write it in the description :)

Comment: Haha, yes, that's what I've done so far. But then of course tools like my IDE don't properly pick it up. So I was hoping for some secret YARD way of expressing this...

Comment: How does your IDE handle `Enumerable#inject`, as this is similar situation?

Comment: It gracefully ignores it: there are no YARD style documentation blocks on the MRI method stubs which RubyMine (my IDE) uses to generate the documentation here. So whenever it doesn't know what a given method returns, it simply forgoes hinting the type.